# Spring boot - How can I aggrupate and sort in Spring and Mongo?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am making a Spring boot service and in a collection I have to find all documents whose field 'unidadNegocio' has the value that I pass by argument, then aggrupate all elements that have the same value in a field 'aceptado' and then order those documents by a date (as a string) that is stored in a field 'fecha_estadistica'.

So far I am falling even at sorting them by a date with this attempt in my repository template:

```
@Query("{'unidadNegocio': ?0}" +
       ".{ $sort: { 'fecha_estadistica' : 1, 'aceptado' : 1 } }")
List<ProductoComprado> findByUnidadNegocioIgnoreCaseAndOrder(String centro);
```

Any help is very welcomed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your method as it follows:

```
@Query(value = "{'unidadNegocio': ?0}")
List<ProductoComprado> findByUnidadNegocioIgnoreCaseAndOrder(String centro, Sort sort);
```

And then when you invoke your repository do the following:

```
Sort sort = Sort.by("aceptado", "fecha_estadistica");
List<ProductoComprado> results = repository.findByUnidadNegocioIgnoreCaseAndOrder("negocio", sort);
```

Or alternative you can do simply the following:

```
@Query(value = "{'unidadNegocio': ?0}", sort = "{ 'aceptado' : 1, 'fecha_estadistica' : 1 }")
List<ProductoComprado> findByUnidadNegocioIgnoreCaseAndOrder(String centro);
```

and then simply call your repository method.

Remember that the values in sorting specification must be the names that you have in the entity field, not in the MongoDB collection. In this answer I am assuming that `fecha_estadistica` and `aceptado` are field names in your Entity class.